# Order Generated Images Alphabetically

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode

I have a webapp that generates a barcode.

It works fine, but I was wondering if there was a way to programmatically sort the results in alphabetical order.

The app takes information from a  database, basically initials of a longer name, to generate the barcode along with a date and a value of how many should be generated.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT dbo.groups.groupname, dbo.groups.description FROM dbo.groups ORDER BY dbo.groups.groupname ASC
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();


        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {

                ListItem item = new ListItem();
                ListItem item2 = new ListItem();
                item.Text = sdr["groupname"].ToString() + "-" + sdr["description"].ToString();
                item.Value = sdr["groupname"].ToString();
                item2.Text = sdr["description"].ToString();
                item2.Value = sdr["description"].ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groupname", groupname);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description);
                groupname.Items.Add(item);

            }
        }

        conn.Close();

    }


for (n = 1; n <= i; n++)
{
        foreach (ListItem item in BarCode.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                string barCode = item.Value + datepicker.Text + n.ToString("D2");

               \\rest of graphics image code
           }
        {
}
```

Item.Value is from the database that gets the names from a parametrized  sql command.

Since the barcode being generated is 1 item that is in a foreach loop, it will generate an amount input by the user.

The barcode has a format Description from database - date - number. If I choose more than one value, such as 2, it will generate the barcodes as such:

```
AADATE01 ABDATE01 ACDATE01
AADATE02 ABDATE02 ACDATE02
```

My question is, can you sort the order the barcodes are being generated in?
The SQL Query does have an Ordered By clause. Ideally it should generate like this:

```
AADATE01 AADATE02
ABDATE01 ABDATE02
ACDATE01 ACDATE02
```

I'm not concerned with formatting, I'm concerned with the order, is there are way to get all of AA first and then List the next group and so forth?